# enable a dropdown list on button click event in HTML

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I want to enable a dropdown list on the click event of a button, but in my case with the following code, the dropdown is enabling for few seconds and then getting disabled in the aspx page.

`enable` function to enable the dropdown:

```
function enable() {
    $("#ddlBranch").prop("disabled", false);
}
```

Dropdown list code:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group m-r-sm">
        <label for='rf_name'>Branch</label>
        <select id="ddlBranch"  class="m-b-sm  w-lg form-control" onchange="ViewHistoricData()">
            <option value="ALL" selected="selected">ALL</option>
        </select>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnClientId" runat="server" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Button Click code:

```
<button id="btnViewHistoricData" class="btn bg-dark" onclick= "enable();" >View Historic Data</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have remove 'disabled'.

```
function enable() {
   $("#ddlBranch").removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

**RIGHT WAY TO DISABLE / ENABLE** with jQuery would be

```
function enable() {
   $("#ddlBranch").attr('disabled',false);
}
```

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#attr-fe-disabled

Comment: Its not working, the same thing is happening. Getting enabled for few seconds and then getting disabled.

Comment: @Sujith Edited the answer, use the second option. $("#ddlBranch").attr('disabled',false);

Comment: its also not working. I am using disable code in the document.ready function. Is it enable function not working due to this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  $("#btnViewHistoricData").click(function() {
       $("#ddlBranch").prop("disabled", true);
    });

    <button id="btnViewHistoricData" class="btn bg-dark" >View Historic Data</button>
```